# Помогите разобраться со скриптом

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

1. Посоветуйте какие нибудь учебники по *ява-скрипту* и, может быть, по верстке, для совсем новичков, чтоб хорошо расписаны азы были, и, если можно, Русскоязычные.
2. Проверьте, правильно ли я трактую данный код (и, если можно, укажите на ошибки в трактовке):

```
 //обьявляем обертку функции: функцию  "getSlider()"            
        function getSlider() {
 //обращаемся к селектору с идентификатором "slides", вызываем функцию:   
 slidesjs
            $('#slides').slidesjs({
//вызываем обект "play"             
                play: {
//Вызывается переменная "active" с параметром: "true"
                  active: true,
//Вызывается переменная "auto" с параметром: "true"
                  auto: true,
//Вызывается переменная "interval" с параметром: "4000"
                  interval: 4000,
//Вызывается переменная "swap" с параметром: "true"
                  swap: true,
//Вызывается переменная "effect" с параметром: "fade"
                  effect: "fade"
//Вызывается функция "navigation"
                }, navigation: {
//Вызывается переменная "effect" с параметром: "fade"
                  effect: "fade"
//Вызывается функция "pagination"
                },
                pagination: {
//Вызывается переменная "effect" с параметром: "fade"
                  effect: "fade"
//Вызывается объект "effect"
                },
                effect: {
 //Вызывается объект "fade"
                  fade: {
//Вызывается переменная "speed" с параметром: "1000"
                    speed: 1000,
//Вызывается переменная "crossfade" с параметром: "true"

                    crossfade: true
                  }
                }
              });   
        };
        });
```

Comment: вопрос не по теме, но подскажу - аctive, auto, interval итд это не некие переменные, а свойства объекта, который является значением свойства play анонимного объекта, являющегося первым и единственным аргументом метода slidesjs - объекта, полученного с помощью вызова функции $ с аргументом '#slides'. А true, 4000, fade - это значения этих свойств. Короче говоря, перед нами вызов метода, аргументом которого является объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Посоветуйте какие нибудь учебники по ява-скрипту и, может быть, по верстке, для совсем новичков, чтоб хорошо расписаны азы были, и, если можно, Русскоязычные.

http://learn.javascript.ru

> Проверьте, правильно ли я трактую данный код (и, если можно, укажите на ошибки в трактовке)

1. "Вызывается что-то", а не "Вызываеться что-то".
2. Переменные вызываться не могут. Только функции.
3. Обёрток функции там нет.
4. А функции только: `getSlider`, `$` и `slidesjs`.
5. Ни одной переменной в коде нет.

Остальное пояснять желания нет.